# RSS *notifier* app?

Tags: software-recommendation, rss

I looked over a few of the RSS apps on the Mac, but they all seem to be "larger" that what I need.

What I'm looking for is an app that checks certain feeds for articles matching a set of keywords, and then notifies me of a match.

I *don't* want to read the article in that app, I'll do that in Safari. But I do want some sort of aggressive notification - to the point of texting me on my iPhone if that's what it takes. An alternative to that last one would be an iPhone app.

Comment: Ok, so... IFTTT has the problem that you can only filter on one term, so it doesn't really work the way I need on it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [Yahoo pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) that filters your RSS feeds for those specific keywords. Then create an RSS feed of the pipe's output. Use that to create a [Feed Channel trigger](https://ifttt.com/feed) in IFTTT that texts you, emails you, notifies your iphone, etc. It’s a multilayered approach, I admit, but I think it could work for you if you don’t mind using those services.

Comment: Actually the Yahoo pipe might wouldn't even be necessary; IFTTT already has the ability to use RSS feeds with a filter "New feed item matches".

Comment: Holy, Pipes is COOL. Thank you for that tip. You too ILI!

Answer (score 0):

Try RSS Bot - News Notifier from the Mac App Store! https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/rss-bot-news-notifier/id605732865?mt=12

Comment: The filtering is per-feed, whereas I want sort of the opposite, a single filter across all of my feeds. Additionally there's no way to do any sort of "AND", which isn't absolutely required, but much simpler to use.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your request :/ For the record, you can set different filters for a particular feed just dividing every keyword or sentence typing "," in the end!